# How does the `data-include` attribute likely work?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm analyzing a site and I see that there is a `data-include` attribute on a div.

I see that `data-` is part of the HTML 5 spec according to a Resig article.

I can also see that the div is being replaced by some response HTML as it fires off an xhr request to the server.  This mechanism is basically used to load modules client side.

```
<div data-include='some.path'></div>
```

The question I have is how is the XHR fired off?

I'm used to accessing the DOM via IDs `#` or classes `.`, or selectors of some sort.

I see no selector so I can't figure out how it is done?

Here is a list of js according to Chrome

[image]

Comment: The site you're looking at. What javascript libraries is it using ? If you don't see any selectors then it's likely not using Jquery. Perhaps Angular.js ?

Comment: If using jQuery this attribute can be picked up with .data('include') which will give you the value in your script, which you can then operate on.

Comment: @Tchi - I added in a list to the question

Comment: @Chrill - nice to know, but how does jQuery do it then, I mean what is the DOM method for searching by attribute ?

Comment: I think we need to see the javascript code too. Perhaps there's a selector but might not be obvious to your eyes.

Comment: Probably done with jQuery based on the given libraries.

Comment: I agree with @Chrillewoodz, you can try downloading the un-minified version of the js scripts.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz No, it has nothing to do with jQuery. `csi.js` is a standalone library, jquery is presumably being used for other things on that page.

Comment: @Barmar Ye I just read your answer, never even heard of csi.js. Gonna have to look it up :)

Comment: Neither did I, I found it when I googled `data-include`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data-include` is used by [csi.js](https://github.com/LexmarkWeb/csi.js) -- client side includes. An element with `data-include='URL'` is automatically replaced with the contents of the URL.

Comment: I was just thinking how I could write this in like 10 lines of code using jQuery.

Comment: @cadegalt would have been great if you mentioned that in your original question.

Comment: @cadegalt The actual code is 35 lines, but most of it is XMLHttpRequest boilerplate. Yet they still felt the need to provide a minimized version.

Comment: Yep, it's for modern browsers as it does not include the facade pattern to abstract all the types of ajax requests.   The jQuery for an ajax request is in the hundreds of lines of code I think.  I like this style of coding, simple, modern and to the point.

Answer (score 2):

You can select DOM elements by data attribute, either by their value or just the presence of them. For example, using jQuery, this selector would give you all the elements with a `data-include` attribute: `$("[data-include]")`. So roughly if you wanted to load a bunch of URL's given by the data-attribute `data-include` in a bunch of divs, you could do something like this.

```
$('[data-include]').each( function() {
  var path = $(this).data('include');
  // Do something with this path
});
```

That is how you would gather up those elements, then I assume you loop through them and load the scripts from that attribute. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the source code of [csi.js](https://github.com/LexmarkWeb/csi.js/blob/master/src/csi.js), I learned that this is how it's done:

```
window.onload = function() {

  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
      i;
  for (i in elements) {

    if (elements[i].hasAttribute && elements[i].hasAttribute('data-include')) {
        fragment(elements[i], elements[i].getAttribute('data-include'));
    }
  }
  function fragment(el, url) {
    var localTest = /^(?:file):/,
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        status = 0;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        /* if we are on a local protocol, and we have response text, we'll assume things were sucessful */
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            status = xmlhttp.status;
        }
        if (localTest.test(location.href) && xmlhttp.responseText) {
            status = 200;
        }
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && status == 200) {
            el.outerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }

      try { 
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      } catch(err) {
        /* todo catch error */
      }
  }
}
```

He basically just uses vanilla JS and grabs all the elements, loops through them to see which have the attribute of `data-include` and then makes a new http request for each attribute that he finds. It's really straight forward and could be written way shorter in jQuery, but it's not necessary since you would have to include a whole library for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, many JS libraries use whatever- prefixes to many things. Check what library the site is using and then read it's documentation to understand why it's there.